# Add style_formats after tinyMCE editor is loaded

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When you init a tinyMCE Editor you can pass the following custome styles.

```
tinyMCE.init({ style_formats: [{ title: 'flow', selector: 'img', styles: { 'float': 'left', 'margin-right': '5px' } }]});
```

But, what if I want to give tinyMCE som custom styles after it is loaded? How can I do that. For example, I have been able to add the style_formats to the tinyMCE editor object like this.

```
tinyMCE.editors[0].settings["style_formats"] = [{title:'flow', selector:'img', styles: {'float' : 'left'}}];
```

But the editor it self does not get updated. Is there any way to tell tinyMCE to reload it self? Or is there another way to update a editor on the fly?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really mean to add it after or just append to existing settings? As of version 4.0.13 there is now a new property you can use during init called **style_formats_merge**. Set this property to true and it will concatenate your styles onto the default set.

```
tinymce.init({
    style_formats_merge: true,
    style_formats: [
        {
            title: 'Line Height',
            items: [
                { title: 'Normal Line Height', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '100%' } },
                { title: 'Line Height + 10%', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '110%' } },
                { title: 'Line Height + 50%', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '150%' } },
                { title: 'Line Height + 100%', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '200%' } }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After your tinymce configuration file you can extend your tinymce settings in a new js file by adding the following code to it.

```
jQuery.extend(tinymce.settings,
{
   style_formats: [
        {
            title: 'Line Height',
            items: [
                { title: 'Normal Line Height', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '100%' } },
                { title: 'Line Height + 10%', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '110%' } },
                { title: 'Line Height + 50%', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '150%' } },
                { title: 'Line Height + 100%', inline: 'span', styles: { "line-height": '200%' } }
            ]
        }
]
 });
```